# Removing extra info after merging two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The following code adds **x** after *Name* and *Price* as well as two additional columns **Name_y**  and **Price_y**. How can I remove these items?

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3','4.4.4.4','5.5.5.5'],
    'ID':['101','202','303','404','505'],
    'Name':['aqua','noctua','ytube','tech','logi'],
    'Price':[100,200,300,400,500]
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3','4.4.4.4','6.6.6.6'],
    'ID':['101','202','303','404','606'],
    'Name':['atlas','noctua','ytube','tech','smash'],
    'Price':[600,700,800,900,990]

    })
print(df)
        IP   ID    Name  Price
0  1.1.1.1  101    aqua    100
1  2.2.2.2  202  noctua    200
2  3.3.3.3  303   ytube    300
3  4.4.4.4  404    tech    400
4  5.5.5.5  505    logi    500

print(df1)
        IP   ID    Name  Price
0  1.1.1.1  101   atlas    600
1  2.2.2.2  202  noctua    700
2  3.3.3.3  303   ytube    800
3  4.4.4.4  404    tech    900
4  6.6.6.6  606   smash    990

new=df1.merge(df,indicator=True,how='left', on=['IP', 'ID']).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only'].drop('_merge',1)
print(new)

   IP        ID  Name_x   Price_x Name_y  Price_y
4  6.6.6.6  606  smash      990    NaN      NaN
```

**The expected result is:**

```
   IP        ID  Name   Price 
4  6.6.6.6  606  smash  990
```

I simply don't know what needs to be changed... Thank you!

Comment: just as an aside, am I right in saying that u r looking for items in df1 where IP and ID are not in df?

Answer (score 1):

Idea is filter only columns for merge, here `IP` and `ID` for `df`:

```
new=(df1.merge(df[['IP','ID']],indicator=True,how='left', on=['IP', 'ID'])
        .loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
        .drop('_merge',1))
```

Or if removed `on` parameter then merge by intersection of columns names, here `IP`, `ID`:

```
new=(df1.merge(df[['IP','ID']],indicator=True,how='left')
        .loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
        .drop('_merge',1))
```

---

```
print(new)
        IP   ID   Name  Price
4  6.6.6.6  606  smash    990
```